# Retornar dados da minha tabela formatando no html

Tags: php, query

Tenho uma função dentro de minha classe para listar dados; abaixo segue o código:

```
public function listadados(){

       try{
           //retornar um array
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_cadcli";
           $lista = $this->con->conectar()->prepare($sql);
           $lista->execute();
           $retDados = array ( $lista-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
           print_r($retDados);
       }catch(PDOException $erro_2){
           echo 'erro'.$erro_2->getMessage();       
       }
}
```

Desejo colocar o retorno que esta abaixo. dentro de um html

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [idcad_cliente] => 1
                    [nm_cliente] => Rodrigo Zanetti
                    [email_cliente] => jau@webconsul.com.br
                    [senha_cliente] => 7ik3ikelek
                    [id_identpess] => 1
                    [img] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [idcad_cliente] => 2
                    [nm_cliente] => Rodrigo Zanetti
                    [email_cliente] => jau@webconsul.com.br
                    [senha_cliente] => k3ik3ik3ikkejeh
                    [id_identpess] => 1
                    [img] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [idcad_cliente] => 3
                    [nm_cliente] => Adriana Silva Souto
                    [email_cliente] => drissouto@gmail.com
                    [senha_cliente] => k3ikeikeikeieçeoel
                    [id_identpess] => 1
                    [img] => 
                )
```

Essa tela abaixo é minha template, onde desejo retornar os valores formatados. nome em baixo de  NOME: email em baixo de EMAIL, como uma tabela.

listadados();

?>

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                   <th>Deletar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Por quê você não faz `return $retDados` em seu método e utilizar o [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) para percorrê-los, exibindo no HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talves isso seja a solução :

**Método listadados()**

```
 public function listadados(){

       try{
           //retornar um array
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_cadcli";
           $lista = $this->con->conectar()->prepare($sql);
           $lista->execute();
           $retDados = $lista-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

           return $retDados;

       }catch(PDOException $erro_2){
           echo 'erro'.$erro_2->getMessage();       
       }
}
```

Assim o array com os registros será retornado e poderá ser usado da seguinte forma.

```
<?php
  $objeto = new NomeDaClasse;
  $clientes = NomeDaClasse->listadados();
?>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                   <th>Deletar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <?php foreach($clientes as $cliente) : ?>
                   <tr>
                     <td><?=$cliente['nm_cliente']?></td>
                     <td><?=$cliente['email_cliente']?></td>
                     <td><a href="?id_cliente=<?=$cliente['idcad_cliente']?>&action=editar">Editar</a></td>
                     <td><a href="?id_cliente=<?=$cliente['idcad_cliente']?>&action=deletar">Deletar</a></td>
                   </tr>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Com o **return** os dados podem ser passados para uma variável e serem percorridos por um loop **foreach**.

Essa parte de **Editar** e **Deletar** coloquei os parâmetros presumindo que fosse ser usado o **$_GET** já que não falou nada sobre essa parte.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito como eu precisava. Obrigado.

Comment: @RodrigoZanetti considere aceitar a resposta. Veja como em: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117