# Erro ao fazer o delete com PHP usando classe PDO e orientação a objetos

Tags: php, html, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou fazendo um *delete* no meu formulário `manut_usuario`, abaixo está o meu método para deletar que está na classe `usuario.class.php`;

```
public function DelUsu($id){
        try{
        $delUsu = "DELETE FROM usuario WHERE idu_usujport = :id ";
        $delUsu = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($delUsu);
        $delUsu->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $delUsu->execute();
        $delUsu->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $delUsu;
        echo 'deletado';
        }
       catch(PDOException $erro_5){
        echo 'erro'.$erro_5->getMessage();
        }
    }//Metodo Delete dados.
```

No meu formulário abaixo está a forma que eu faço para deletar os dados passando para o método `DelUsu`

```
<?php       //crio um array para recuperar os dados e mostrar no formulario.

             $objeto = new Usuario();
             $usuario = $objeto->LerDadosUsu();
             foreach($usuario as $usuario):
             ?>
             <tr>
             <td><?php print $usuario['nom_usujauport'] ?></td>
             <td><?php print $usuario['ema_usujauport'] ?></td>
             <td><?php print $usuario['sen_usujauport'] ?></td>
             <!--FINAL DO ARRAY(RECUPERANDO SEM ERROS)-->             


              <!--DELETAR-->
              <?php
              $usuario =  new Usuario();   
              $id="";    //zero a variável ID para pegar sempre a selecionada pelo administrador   
              if(isset($_POST['excl_usu'])){
              $usuario->DelUsu($id);             
              echo "Excluido";
              }else{
              echo "Não Excluido!!";
              }

              ?>
```

Ao executar o programa e fazer o delete clicando no botão `<"excl_usu">` dá o erro abaixo

> erroSQLSTATE[HY000]: General errorExcluido

Abaixo segue meu formulário onde termino como o `foreach`.

```
    <?php
         $objeto = new Usuario();
         $usuario = $objeto->LerDadosUsu();
         foreach($usuario as $usuario):
         ?>
         <tr>
         <td><?php print $usuario['nom_usujauport'] ?></td>
         <td><?php print $usuario['ema_usujauport'] ?></td>
         <td><?php print $usuario['sen_usujauport'] ?></td>
         <!--FUNÇÕES PARA CARREGAR DADOS NAS ALTERAÇÕES-->             


          <!--DELETAR-->
          <?php
          $usuario =  new Usuario();   
          $id="";       
          if(isset($_POST['excl_usu'])){
          $usuario->DelUsu($id);             
          echo "Excluido";
          }else{
          echo "Não Excluido!!";
          }

          ?>
          <!--FINAL DELETAR-->
          <!--ALTERAR-->
          <?php


          ?> 
         <!--FINAL ALTERAR-->


<td><p data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">


         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-title="Editar"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"  nome="alterar" id="alterar"><i class="fa fa-edit">&nbsp;&nbsp;Alterar</i></button></p></td>

    <td><data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " nome="excl_usu" id="excl_usu"><i class="fa fa-trash-o">&nbsp;&nbsp;Excluir</i></button></p></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
             <?php
             endforeach;
             ?>
             </form>
<div class="clearfix" align="center"></div>
<ul class="pagination pull-right">
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
</ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
          <form action="" id="frm_atu_usu" name="frm_atu_usu" method="POST" >
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Editar Usuario</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Nome:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Email:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha:"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-footer ">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sucessful btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Atualizar</button>
         </div></form>
        </div>

       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Onde termina seu `foreach`? Você está fazendo a exclusão dentro do loop? Isso não excluiria o mesmo registro múltiplas vezes?

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss, segue o codigo para mostrar onde esta o final do foreach... o meu final do foreach termina depois de uma janela modal da qual faço os update...

Comment: A sua tabela no HTML está completamente desestruturada. Por favor, reveja seu código. Não faz sentido ter `</tbody>` e `</table>` dentro do loop e há um `<tr>` sobrando na linha anterior à `</tbody>`. Estude melhor a resposta dada em [outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210213/5878) e entenda como isso é feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está certo a chamada do objeto conexão com o banco de dados ?

```
$delUsu = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($delUsu);
```

Remove essas linhas da sua função não se usa para DELETE método fetch

```
$delUsu->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
return $delUsu;
```

Adicione essa:

```
echo 'deletado'.$delUsu->rowCount(); //vai retornar a quantidade de registro deletado
```

Comment: Henrique bom dia!!, era isso mesmo. A linha onde eu faço a chamada ta certa porem onde tinha o return era mesmo onde estava o problema após removê-la, ficou certo....como eu precisaval. Obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoZanetti por nada :).